# Can I fit larger rotors on a Surly Karate Monkey fork?

Tags: brakes

I have a [Surly Karate Monkey fork](http://surlybikes.com/parts/forks/karate_monkey_fork) that has 160mm rotors.

I'd like to upgrade to [Clarks M2 brakes](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/au/en/clarks-m2-hydraulic-disc-brake/rp-prod135586) with 180mm rotors.

How can I tell if those calipers/rotors will fit my fork?

Answer (score 7):

You will need an adaptor, but those are common. The only trick is which exact one you need, basically which way you need to move the caliper. The really simple ones just lift it straight away from the mounts like this [Hope one](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/au/en/hope-is-to-is-disc-brake-adaptor/rp-prod13736):

[image: hope rear disc brake adaptor]

You might want to [move it up instead](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/au/en/shimano-mount-adaptor-front-post-to-is/rp-prod13743):

[image: Shimano front disk mounts]

I expect that the 180mm Shimano adaptor is what you want but you should check carefully to make sure the mount spacing is correct.

The process is not tricky, but [this blog post](http://markie.com.au/mtb/blog.asp?BlogID=44&BlogName=Brake-disk-rotor-size-upgrade-180-to-200mm%2C-160-to-180mm) explains it in more detail.

Comment: Moz is partly right but you need to be careful as adapters are either IS or post mount. I am pretty sure your fork is post mount but you'd need to check as you don't give photos of your bike and I have no idea if Surly changed it in the past. The hope adapters is an IS adapted and the ones below are post-mount. Either way order the right size of the right type and you're sorted.